# Connecting to local wifi and wifi at same time

Tags: wifi

I have a RPi 3 B with a WiFi dongle. I'd like to connect the built-in RPi WiFi (wlan0) to a wifi router that is not connected to the internet, just local. I'd also like to connect the WiFi dongle (wlan1) to a different WiFi router that is connected to the internet. This I have done, however internet doesn't work unless I disconnect from the local WiFi. Is there a way I can connect to both and have internet?

Thanks

Comment: While connecting to both WLANs, can you get the output of _route_ command?

Answer (score 2):

This is a routing problem. It seems that your default route is set to the router on the local network, connected on interface **wlan0**. But there is no internet. For example if your internet router has the ip address 192.168.4.1 then try to adjust the default route with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo ip route del default dev wlan0
rpi ~$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.4.1 dev wlan1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up routes to direct traffic to the correct WLAN. Here is a link that should help as it seems to be very similar to your requested configuration.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=38379

Comment: Please try adding more detail to the answer than just a rough description and a link.